# How to get a JSONObject into JSONArray

Tags: ios, iphone, json, xcode, xcode5

I need get a JSONObject into my JSONArray. 
**This is my JSON:**

```
[
{
    "id": 9,
    "holder_rut": 22222222,
    "holder_name": "Maria Alcala",
    "rut": 22222222,
    "name": "Maria Alcala",
    "refunds_view": [
        {
            "id": 52,
            "request_number": 987654,
            "policy_code": "200000000",
            "company": "Benefits",
            "beneficiary_id": 9,
            "concept": "Prueba More Ocho",
            "date": "2013-05-05",
            "amount": 20001,
            "deductible_amount": 0,
            "max_applied": 0,
            "yearly_balance": 98,
            "payment_amount": 14001,
            "payment_method": "Deposito",
            "bank": "Estado",
            "account_number": "2345678",
            "payment_date": "2014-05-05",
            "created_at": "2014-06-18 21:48:03"
        },
        {
            "id": 99,
            "request_number": 2244665,
            "policy_code": "200000000",
            "company": "Benefits",
            "beneficiary_id": 9,
            "concept": "Prueba More Ocho",
            "date": "2014-04-29",
            "amount": 20001,
            "deductible_amount": 0,
            "max_applied": 0,
            "yearly_balance": 98,
            "payment_amount": 14001,
            "payment_method": "Deposito",
            "bank": "Estado",
            "account_number": "2345678",
            "payment_date": "2014-05-29",
            "created_at": "2014-06-27 23:21:52"
        }
    ]
}
]
```

In this JSON I get two JSONObjects with id = 52 and id = 99

I need getting the differents Objects into **refunds view** using xcode.

My code to parse this JSON is here:

```
NSDictionary *jsonResponse = (NSDictionary *) [jsonParser objectWithString:responseData error:nil];//I'm a Json Refunds
self.list = [jsonResponse valueForKey:@"refunds_view"];
refunds_view = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (NSDictionary *each_refunds in self.list) {
    //NSLog(@"each_refound %@",each_refunds);

    Refunds *refunds = [[Refunds alloc] initWithJSONData:each_refunds];
    [refunds_view addObject:refunds]; 
}
```

**Refunds.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Refunds : NSObject

-(id)initWithJSONData:(NSDictionary*)data;

 @property (assign) NSNumber *refunds_id;
 @property (assign) NSNumber *request_number;
 @property (strong) NSString *policy_code;
 @property (strong) NSString *company;

 @end
```

**Refunds.m**

```
#import "Refunds.h"

@implementation Refunds 

@synthesize refunds_id;
@synthesize request_number;
@synthesize policy_code;
@synthesize company;
-(id)initWithJSONData:(NSArray*)data{
self = [super init];
if(self){
    NSLog(@"initWithJSONData method called ");

    refunds_id =  [data valueForKey:@"id"];
    request_number = [data valueForKey:@"request_number"];
    policy_code = [data valueForKey:@"policy_code"];
     company = [data valueForKey:@"company"];
  }
  return self;
  }
  @end
```

Comment: Go to json.org and spend the 5-10 minutes it takes to learn the JSON syntax.  Then understand that a JSON "object" maps to an NSDictionary and a JSON "array" maps to an NSArray.  Use NSLog to check what you have along the way -- NSDictionarys dump between `{}` brackets and NSArrays dump between `()` brackets.

Comment: (This is a dupe 1000 times over, but I'm not going to take the time to look up the reference.)

Answer (score 2):

Your JSON is an array, but you are extracting a NSDictionary.

```
NSArray *jsonResponse = [NSJSONSerialization 
    JSONObjectWithData:jsonStringAsNSData options:0 error:&error];
NSDictionary *jsonDictionary = jsonResponse.firstObject;
NSArray *objects = jsonDictionary[@"refunds_view"];
```

Comment: Thanks @Mundi. You are an example to extracting a NSDictionary.

Comment: Thanks @Mundi but *objects content a two id's content in refunds_view. I need getting all data of the id = 99 and id = 52 separately.

Comment: @jghg02 - So?  Write some software.  You know how to access elements of an array, right?